# nginx proxy for inducing delay to avoid ddos

Tags: nginx, proxy, ddos

We are currently using a delay for repeated requests based on an algorithm which decides on the amount of time to delay the response to slow down the requesting system. Our site runs in apache and php.

The problem is, this tactic affects our system too since the processes that are sleeping are locked.

So alternately, we are thinking of the following approach.

1. nginx proxies any incoming request and pass on to the main site in apache and php
2. The site decides the amount of delay time based on the current algorithm.
3. Instead of sleeping in-process, it will just add the delay time as a custom header and return the response.
4. nginx will then check if the header exists and if exists, will send the request to another application in nodejs
5. The nodejs application will just read the delay time and put the request to timeout after the delay time and return the response with the delay header with "success" as value
6. The nginx will then send the request to the main application with the header
7. If the incoming request has the header with "success" as value, it will not do any more delaying operations on the request and instead, it will just deliver the normal response.

What would be a good nginx configuration to achieve this?

foot note: Using header as a flag is just one of the options we are considering. We also tried custom status code which didn't work. We also tried one of the standard status code which also creating problems returning the initial status code to the browser instead of the status code from the latest response.

Any other suggestions also welcome. I understand, there are other high level options to address ddos, but this is a necessary feature for our application as it is also used as an api for several other sites.

Comment: Have you seen http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html ?

Comment: I did. We have a little bit more complex logic in our limit setting. We need to do some whitelist and some requests are cheaper than some others and need not be limited, etc.

Comment: Well, then I would use nginx lua module

Comment: @user3638011 did you end up implementing this? And if so, would you care to share the nginx part? We are looking at building something very similar, but at the moment we don't even know if it's feasible.

Comment: Sorry, I missed out the question. The answer is nope. I just didn't want to spend more time on this. I'm still in the lookout for a solution myself still